# How to show a spinner when fetching data with httpClient in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a service in my Angular App which is used to retrive some data from my API.

I would be able to show a spinner to the user while that data is being fetched.

How should i archieve it?

My service looks like this:

```
export class MenuComponibileService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private adapter: MenuComponibileAdapter) { }

  getMenuComponibile(idNegozio: string, piva: string, lang: string, type: string, idPlu: number): Observable<MenuComponibile[]>{
    return this.http
    .get(`${Globals.API_URL}/mc/${piva}/${idNegozio}/${idPlu}`, {params: { lang, type }})
    .pipe(map((data: any[]) => data.map(item => this.adapter.adapt(item))));
  }
}
```

And i get the data like:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.menuComponibileService
    .getMenuComponibile(this.idNegozio.toString(), this.piva, 'IT', this.tipo, this.plu.id)
    .subscribe((data) => {
      this.menuComponibile = data;
    });
  }
```

I was going to add like a variable loading = true and i was going to set it inside the subscribe like this:

```
  loading = true;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.menuComponibileService
    .getMenuComponibile(this.idNegozio.toString(), this.piva, 'IT', this.tipo, this.plu.id)
    .subscribe((data) => {
      this.menuComponibile = data;
      this.loading = false;
    });
  }
```

when based on loading value i was going to show or not the spinner, but how should it be done correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've pointed out, you can do it that way, or if you want something more RXJS related, you can use `defer` & `finalize`

You can create a function that handles the observable like

```
 get GetMenuComponibile(): Observable<any>{
    return defer(() => {
      this.loading = true;
      return this.menuComponibileService
     .getMenuComponibile(this.idNegozio.toString(), this.piva, 'IT', this.tipo, this.plu.id)
     .finalize(() => this.loading = false)
    });
  }
```

Then you can call it like

```
  this.GetMenuComponibile.subscribe((data) => {
    this.menuComponibile = data;
    this.loading = false;
  });
```

However, it's a syntactically more complex version of what you've already proposed.